# Save query selector in variable to append doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to save an html element inside a variable and than append that element with childelements. I can append that element with the usual jquery selector but not with the variable. Why?

Here is my snippet:

```
var elements, UserTableWidget = {

    elements: {
       pagination: $("#pageNumbers")
    },

    init: function() {
        elements = this.elements;

        elements.pagination.append("<li>test</li>") // works not
        $("#pageNumbers").append("<li>test</li>") // works
    },
}
```

Comment: It looks like a dom ready state problem

Comment: The ` pagination: $("#pageNumbers")` is executed before dom ready but the `init` method is called after dom ready

Comment: The init function is called as last element in my body(script tag). It should be already there right?

Comment: userTableWidget.init() will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is everything so complicated? I simplified some of it.

```
$(function(){

  var UserTableWidget = {
    elements: {
      pagination: $("#pageNumbers")
    },

    init: function() {
      this.elements.pagination.append("<li>test</li>");
    },
  }

  UserTableWidget.init()
  // same as: UserTableWidget.elements.pagination.append("<li>test</li>");
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, `this.elements.pagination` is initialized to `("#pageNumbers")` probably before the dom is ready. When you call `init()` later, it uses the value calculated before (empty jQuery collection), so nothing is appended.